# Writing a parser in JavaScript for matrix arithmetic

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am currently writing a program that will solve matrix equations, and at present, I am working on getting the parser to work. However, I do not know where to start.

I have an array of strings which keep track of both the matrices and the operators. For example, the equation

```
[[0, 0],[4, 5]] + [[4, 8], [12, 6]]
```

would be stored as follows:

```
variables = ["$", "+", "$"]
matrices = [[[0, 0],[4, 5]], [[4, 8], [12, 6]]
```

As such, each "$" symbol represents a matrix in a different array. I also want to be able to wrap my matrices in different expressions, for instance:

```
det([[0, 0],[4, 5]]) + inv([[0, 0],[4, 5]] + [[4, 8], [12, 6]])
```

Where det and inv correspond to determinant and inverse.

which in my code, would be stored as:

```
variables = ["d", "e", "t", "(", "$", ")", "+", "i", "n", "v", "(", "$", "+", "$", ")"]
matrices = [ [[0, 0],[4, 5]], [[0, 0],[4, 5]],  [[4, 8], [12, 6]] ]
```

My intuition is to use context free grammars to build a parse tree, as regular expressions would not work given the parentheses... (?). I am also considering simply converting my expressions into postfix notation and seeing if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Building a parse tree using a context-free grammar strikes me as the best overall approach. (If you're unfamiliar with context-free grammars and you don't have a relevant text book handy, you could do try reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) on the subject.)

If you look around, you'll find lots of examples of how to write a context-free grammar for arithmetic expressions. (The Wikipedia link above contains an example arithmetic grammar.) It's true that most of these are for simple calculators, not for matrix arithmetic. *But that doesn't matter.*

The important insight for writing parsers is that syntax is just syntax. So the form of a grammar for a calculator is going to be the same regardless of whether the primitive objects being calculated are integers or floating-point numbers or complex numbers or, in your case, arrays. The only difference will be in the syntax for an literal object. You can take this fact even further: how the operators themselves are written does not alter the fundamental structure of the grammar, so you can use the same style for calculators which evaluate, say, boolean expressions using **and**, **or** and **not** operators.

In the case of a simple numeric calculator, literal objects (that is, numbers) usually just pop out of the lexer, since they don't have internal structure. But obviously matrices do have internal structure and regex-based lexers are not ideal for parsing structured text. A better solution is to view the matrix literal as being a sequence of tokens (at a minimum, numbers and the symbols `[`, `]` and `,`), and including in your context-free grammar productions which can be used to parse the matrix.

In effect, the matrix is a comma-separated list of vectors, and each vector is a comma-separated list of numbers. This is *syntactically* the same as any other comma-separated list, or even any delimited list regardless of the precise spelling of the delimiter. (In a grammar for parsing expressions which include function calls, you'd need the same type of production to parse the argument list of a function.)

The basic form of a context-free grammar for a delimited list is the following, where you would substitute X with the type of element in the list:

```
/* Only parses lists with at least one element */
list_of_X: X
         | list_of_X ',' X
```

If empty lists are allowed (probably not the case with matrices, but common in function calls), you combine the above with another pattern:

```
optional_list_of_X: %empty
                  | list_of_X
```

Your grammar would then include productions like:

```
expression: matrix
          | /* ... all the other forms of an expression */

matrix: '[' list_of_vector ']'
vector: '[' list_of_number ']'
```

Here I've used [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples) syntax because it's a common way of writing context-free grammars, but every parser generator has its own idiosyncrasies.